# Javascript not rendering content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I am trying to display content using javascript DOM but every time I run my solution I get a blank page. My HTML file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Radiant HQ</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="navigationcontent"></nav>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/radiant.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My js file looks this way:

```
@import ('../css/style.css');
document.getElementById("navigationcontent").innerHTML=`
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a> </li>
    <li><a href="">About Us</a> </li>
    <li><a href="">Research</a> </li>
    <li><a href="">Contacts</a> </li>
</ul>`;
```

Comment: `@import ('../css/style.css');` why is this in javascript snippet?

Comment: ^ This. And have you looked at your DevTools console for more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works. There is one problem though.

It's getting stuck on the `@import ('../css/style.css');` line. Try removing that whole line and include your CSS some other way. Typically this in done in the head of the document via html.